# How to format a date field into diferente languages in the same MySQL command?

Tags: mysql, datetime, locale

The following will return the day in Italian:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'it_IT';
select date_format('2018/01/01','%W') as day_italian;
```

However I need to convert or format the date into multiple languages, so it would return me another column in English, Japanese, so on...

My problem is that I have to set the locale BEFORE running the select command.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table with three columns: language, weekday (int) and translation. Then you can join on it with over the language and DAYOFWEEK() or WEEKDAY(). Sadly there is no easier way since not a single date-function supports language parameters.